# How To Import Module In Angular Using Path In A Variable

Tags: angular, angular9

I want to `import` my angular `module` using variable name as a path of that `module`. For an example:

When I use this code below, it's working fine:

```js
import('src/app/modules/public/public.module').then(mod => mod.PublicModule);
```

But, when I try to store my `module` path to the some variable, It's not working. For an example, what I was trying before, It's looks like this code below:

```js
const publicPath = 'src/app/modules/public/public.module';
import(publicPath).then(mod => mod.PublicModule);
```

When I trying that code above, **I get some error** like this:

```
core.js:6185 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find module 'app/modules/public/public.module'
Error: Cannot find module 'app/modules/public/public.module'
```

Now, What should I have to do to `import` that `module` with path in a variable?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. In order to get lazy loading working, Angular CLI analyzes the code to create a separate `public.module` bundle with this code:

```js
import('src/app/modules/public/public.module').then(mod => mod.PublicModule);
```

and loads the bundle when needed at runtime. When using a variable, it can not create a bundle anymore as the value is only known at runtime.